# WordPress is not working normally because of htaccess

Tags: wordpress

My apk can be accessed by going to logo-centar.com/app and it works perfectly, and the site itself should be accessed by going to the domain logo-centar.com, however the installation of the wp site is in public_html /wordpress folder which should not be displayed in the url but only the classic domain logo-centar.com and then let's say that you go to the logo-centar.com/o-nama pages, however it doesn't work, even wp-login doesn't work it simply refreshes the page when i try to login . I moved the wordpress site to a subdomain and it works perfectly there, which tells me the problem is somewhere in the htaccess file

Here is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=307,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.logo-centar.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.logo-centar.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wordpress/index.php

</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do yo mean by "apk"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have a python web application in a folder logo-centar.com/app , i got stuck there for some reason i can't access wp-admin , and even my wp site pages don't work.  However, when I move WordPress to a subdomain, everything works fine

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it